# Трансформация html5canvas

Tags: canvas, html5

*Вопрос закрыт :)
Прошу прощения за флуд*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поворот относительно центра делается примерно так, дальше, как сделать то, что нужно вам, думаю, разберетесь сами

```
var d = Math.min(canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.save();

    context.translate( canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2 );
    context.rotate( ROTATION_ANGLE * Math.PI / 180 );
    context.drawImage(context.currImage, -d / 2, -d / 2, d, d);

context.restore();
```

Comment: @Keyten - спасибо, код поправил

На будущее - не обязательно награждать репутацией, палец вверх и принятый ответ и так ее повышают :)

Comment: P.S. решил так:

ctx.save();

ctx.translate(x, y);

ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * angle);

ctx.translate(-x, -y);

// рисуем

ctx.restore();

// если вдруг не поможет - повторить через transform и стандартные матрицы трансформаций :)